# How to clear textarea in JQuery but making it still editable?

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I would like to clean up a text area with javascript. Searching the net I found only jQuery or JavaScript functions to do this, but they don't work for me. After pressing the button called 'AVANTI', I would like the text area to be completely clean and then if the user presses the button again to show him more data from MySQL database. I tried to use the reset() function inside the 'AVANTI' button, but once pressed it is no longer possible to view other data inside the textarea. ***My textarea is overwritten by data everytime I press 'AVANTI' button.***
My main question is where to put `document.getElementById('comments').value = '';` in my JS code?

```html
<html lang="it" dir="ltr">
  <head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js">
        <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
  window.history.replaceState('','',window.location.href)
  });
    $(document).ready(function(){
   $('#comments').bind("cut copy paste",function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
   });
});
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var commentCount = 0;
        $("#avanti").click(function() {
          commentCount += 1 ;
          $("#comments").load("load-comments.php",  {
            commentNewCount: commentCount
          }); });  });
    </script>
    <title>Cherubini Website</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache">
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="-1">
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea name="message" rows="8" cols="80" id="comments"
     readonly="readonly" unselectable="on">
<?php""?>
    </textarea>
    <button id="indietro">INDIETRO</button>
    <button id="avanti">AVANTI</button>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: PHP can't change content that is already displayed in the browser; PHP doesn't run in the browser.

Comment: So I've to do this with JQuery?